# Как скруглить кнопку с одной стороны?

Tags: android

Подскажите, как можно правую сторону Button скруглить, а левую оставить без изменений?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Нашел ответ на свой же вопрос, может кому-то пригодится)

```
<corners
    android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="39dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
    />
```